# On Change To Auto Fill

Tags: reactjs, vite

Following is the code

Input to set All Values at once

```js
<input
   type="text"
   name="setValues"
   placeholder="Set Values"
   onChange={(e) => {
      const value = e.target.value;
      setMaterial(value);
   }}
          
/>
```

Loop Inputs

```js
<td>
   <input
      name="material"
      type="text"
      value={e.Material ? e.Material : material}
      onChange={(event) => {
         handleChange(event, index, "Material");
      }}
   />
</td>
```

I am using ReactJS with Vite. I have a loop in which I can create an infinite number of inputs. For each loop input, I have a single input field which I use to set the value of all inputs at once.

These inputs are part of a form. I have made an onChange event to submit their values. All inputs get values when I enter a value in the main input, but when I click on save, it doesn't trigger the onChange function to pass values along with my other formData. I want that as I input a value in the main input, it should call onChange, and onChange should save the value for all empty inputs related to the material.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, it is not easy to understand your question. Does it make sense to add the actual loop as well, or `handleChange`?

Comment: @pzaenger I have records coming from the backend in the form of an array. I am displaying them using the map function. One record is "material" as it's an input field. Now, I can add as many records as I want. Instead of filling material one by one, I made an input field to set all material at once. Since I was using onChange to get all the values, it should take the programmatic values and save them in formData. However, it is not detecting it as a change. So, it returns me empty fields again when I submit the button.

Comment: '  const handleChange = (event, index, field) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
 
    const newData = [...formData];
    newData[index][field] =
      event.target.type === "checkbox"
        ? event.target.checked
        : event.target.value;
    setFormData(newData);} '